# Почему не выполняется код после завершения потока?

Tags: c, gcc

Поток принудительно завершается вызовом pthread_kill. После вызова должна пройти печать Exiting..., а ее нет. Почему?

```
static void *thread_func(void *args)
{
    puts("Sleeping...");

    for ( ;; ) ;

    return NULL;
}

void main()
{
    pthread_t thread;

    if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_func, NULL) == 0)
    {
        sleep(1);

        pthread_kill(thread, SIGKILL);

        puts("Exiting...");
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> Sleeping...
> Убито

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что нельзя послать сигнал потоку. Сигнал приходит всему процессу. Используйте более "мягкий" метод [pthread_cancel](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cancel.html).